# Popup in client side and pass value from the selected row in a grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
<asp:Panel ID="EditPanel" runat="server" BackImageUrl="~/Light-Gray-Suede1.jpg"
            CssClass="style10" Visible="True" Style="position: absolute; left: 503px; top: 1681px;
            width: 411px; height: 280px; margin-right: 0px;">
            <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_EditExpiresBy" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_EditTitle" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_EditSave" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btn_EditSave_Click" />

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </asp:Panel>
```

In the grid view I have this button, when the user clicks on the edit button the panel pops up and it has to have expireby and respondby date from the same row.

```
  <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Styles/Images/Edit.jpg" CommandName="Edit" runat="server"
                                    ID="btnEdit" ToolTip="Edit Message"  />
 <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="Edit_PopupControlExtender" runat="server" DynamicServicePath=""
                            Enabled="True" ExtenderControlID="" TargetControlID="btnEdit" PopupControlID="EditPanel">
                        </asp:PopupControlExtender>
```

For redirect I pass the value like this <%# Eval("Email", "SendMessage.aspx?Email={0}") %>. And using that value I do the server side code. But how this can be done in client side. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is work around for displaying selected row's data in popup (i did it with repeater for one of my web project):

**javascript to set textboxes with selected row data and then show popup by calling .show()**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showPopupWithRowData(expiryBy, respondBy)
    {
        var txtExpiryBy = $get('<%= this.txt_EditExpiresBy.ClientID %>');
        var txtRespondBy = $get('<%= this.txt_EditTitle.ClientID %>');

        txtExpiryBy.value = expiryBy;
        txtRespondBy.value = respondBy;

        $find('<%= this.Edit_PopupControlExtender.ClientID %>').show();

        return false; 
    }
</script>
```

**markup to call javascript `showPopupWithRowData()` when clicked on button inside Grid**

```
<!-- Note: Replace ColumnNameExpiry and ColumnNameRespond with the original column names -->
<!-- Also note return, since our javascript method always returns false, it will prevent a postback when the image button is clicked --> 
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Styles/Images/Edit.jpg" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" ID="btnEdit" ToolTip="Edit Message" OnClientClick="javascript:return showPopupWithRowData(<%#Eval("ColumnNameExpiry")%>, <%#Eval("ColumnNameRespond")%>);"  />
```